# Using Gulp + Jasmine Testcase with ThreeJs library leads to problems with self reference

Tags: three.js, requirejs, jasmine, gulp

I´m trying to add some testcases to a project using three.js.
The unit i´m trying to test uses THREE.Vector3

I set up a Gulp task for testing with the jasmine library.

my gulp file looks like this:

```
var jasmine = require('gulp-jasmine');
var gulp = require('gulp');
var three = require('../three');

gulp.task('test', function() {
    return gulp.src('jasmine.js')
      .pipe(jasmine());

});
```

where require('../three') is loading the three.js library.

The problem is now that I get the error:

> ReferenceError: self is not defined
>       at Object. (E:\gamesprogrammierung\dodecaeder\Deodecaeder\three.js:8:1)
>       at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
>       at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
>       at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
>       at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
>       at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
>       at require (module.js:380:17)
>       at Object. (E:\gamesprogrammierung\dodecaeder\Deodecaeder\test\gulpfile.js:7:13)
>       at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
>       at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)

As the gulp file runner is not a browser its obvious it cant get a reference to self,
which is used at the start of the three.js file.

```
var THREE = THREE || { REVISION: '58' };

self.console = self.console || {

    info: function () {},
    log: function () {},
    debug: function () {},
    warn: function () {},
    error: function () {}

 };
```

I tried to overwrite the self variable before loading three.js

```
var self = self || {
    console: function () {}
};
```

but the same error appears. Seems to me that require builds up its own context so the defined self variable has no effect.

Has someone an idea how I can get this to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it myself. First I got the require method wrong. This is only for loading
nodejs modules. So it was wrong to load the three.js javascript file with require.
But there is a three.js node module which I installed by

```
npm install three
```

and then use it in the gulp file

```
var THREE = require('three')
```

Still then there was the problem, that the error came that THREE is not defined.
To resolve this I added another line

```
GLOBAL.THREE = THREE;
```

by which I added a global variable to the nodejs context.

Now three js was available.

To get my testcase to call one of my methods I had to add to the jasmine test file

```
fs = require('fs')
myCode = fs.readFileSync('../my-utilsThreeJs.js','utf-8') 
eval(myCode)
```

where my method was defined in my-utilsThreeJs.js.

This is my test method:

```
fs = require('fs')
myCode = fs.readFileSync('../my-utilsThreeJs.js','utf-8') 
eval(myCode)

describe('Vertice count', function() {
    it('test', function() {
        vertices = new Array();
        verticeOne = new THREE.Vector3(0.0,5.0,0.0);
        verticeTwo = new THREE.Vector3(5.0,0.0,0.0);

        vertices[vertices.length] = verticeOne;
        vertices[vertices.length] = verticeTwo;

        result = new THREE.Vector3(2.5,2.5,0.0);

        expect(calculateCenter(vertices)).toEqual(result);

    });
});
```

Now the test case gets called correctly.

Another possibility would maybe have been to load the three.js file also
by fs.readFileSync(...)

But the three.js files needs the variables 'self' and 'window'.
This could be overwritten.
var self = { console: function() {} } 
var window = { requestAnimationFrame: function() {} }

But gulp-jasmine needs the window variable as undefined to work correctly.
This is in minijasminenode/lib/jasmine-version.js the first line with var isCommonJS definition,

So after loading three.js you have to set back the window variable to undefined, 
that should also work.

Comment: have a similar problem, trying to test my custom browser library (not node.js), I wonder if the proper solution for testing non-node.js code is to use gulp-jasmine plugins that use under the belt a phantom browser or similar, like this one: https://github.com/jasmine/gulp-jasmine-browser